# Search for People from within individual site search on Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

On Sharepoint Online, I know that I can search for people from the "Search in Sharepoint" facility in the top left part of the page which shows all sites. This works great, with searches returning categories of "All", "Sites", "Files", "People" and "News".

However, when I use the "Search across sites" facility near the top right of an individual communications site, it shows that it is searching categories of "All", "Files", "Sites" and "News", but "People" is missing. Is there a way I can get the "People" part into the individual site search (so a user searching a name gets the Person's details back rather than only the documents that person had something to do with)